# How can I keep my hotkeyed weapons after getting searched at a casino?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I love using hotkeys to bind my weapons to one button, but after visiting a casino the guards will remove my weapons (except [holdout weapons](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Holdout_weapons)).

Once I leave the casino I'll get my weapons back but my hotkeys will be unbound. This can be aggravating as I'll have to re-key each weapon whenever I step out of a casino. Is there any way to preserve my hotkeys when my courier is disarmed?*

*Also includes being disarmed in locations such as [The Fort](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/The_Fort)

Comment: You could always kill everyone in the casinos. Then they'll never have to take your weapons away ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're playing on PC, the answer seems to lie with the following mod:

[Weapons in Casinos](https://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/587126)

The mod comes with some caveats, namely not brandishing your weapons in the casino, otherwise security will become hostile. If you're not on PC, or you're against using mods, you're a bit out of luck. The game is coded in such a way that it assigns the hotkey as a parameter of the selected weapon. Once that weapon is removed from your inventory, the parameter associated with your hotkey is removed too.

Comment: That's unfortunate as I'm not playing on PC. Thanks for the advice nonetheless, maybe it'll help someone else.